# laravel 5.2 upload image and send email while registering using default auth

Tags: laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2, As it provides auth that creates default Login, registration etc. But I want to customize it. I want my application to allow user upload profile pic while registering and also send an email for account activation. Can I do that? Or do I just need to write my own registration and login models and controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's possible. In your `.env` file you can setup your email information. Then you could do something like this:

```
public function sendEmail($email, $subject, $view, $data = [])
{
        Mail::send($view, $data, function($message) use ($email,$subject)
        {
            $message->to($email)
                    ->subject($subject);
        });
}
```

For uploading files I would recommend dropzone. http://www.dropzonejs.com/